# (Behind), (behind them), (behind their back)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, word-difference

I wonder which choice works naturally and idiomatically in my scenario?

> When those genocidal and bloodthirsty warlords attacked, they burned everywhere, killed many innocent people and ruined many cities. They left nothing ...........

1) behind 
2) behind them 
3) behind their back

Comment: Which one do you  think works based on your research? [behind their back**s**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only context where native speakers use the construction ***behind*** [possessive (pro)noun] **back** (OP's example #3) is the figurative usage...

> *If you've got something to say, say it! Don't just go talking about me **behind my back**!*

...which doesn't really mean *from a **physical location** somewhere behind me* (it nearly always means *when I'm not **present** to hear you myself*).

---

In OP's exact context, native speakers wouldn't normally include ***them*** (example #2), because it's implied by ***behind*** anyway. In some contexts, such as *We were attacked from behind*, the word ***behind*** simply means ***to the rear, at the back***, but when used in conjunction with ***leave / left***, it always refers to *somewhere the referent subject **was previously located*** (the thing is still where it was, but you've moved).

That's to say, if you ***left*** something behind, you must have been with it before (you've moved position, but failed to bring the thing with you). But if you ***see*** something behind you, for example, that doesn't necessarily imply you had it previously, and / or were ever at its current location.

Answer (score 0):

*Behind* works the best. *Behind them* seems to imply that there was literally nothing behind their backs which is the same problem with the third sentence. The phrase "leave nothing behind" is not literal and refers to the act of destroying/taking everything of value. By far I would say 1 is the best choice.